# How to shoot bullets by horizontal in html5 canvas game?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create the a shoot game
but I don't how to make the player shoot shooting bullets by horizontal.

any idea ??? thanks

Here is my javascript code

```js
    bullet = [];

function drawbullet() {
  if (bullet.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < bullet.length; i++) {
     ctx.fillStyle = '#f00';
     ctx.fillRect(bullet[i][0],bullet[i][1],bullet[i][2],bullet[i][3])
   }
}
function movebullet() {
 for (var i = 0; i < bullet.length; i++) {
   if (bullet[i][1] > -11) {
      bullet[i][1] -= 10;
    } else if (bullet[i][1] < -10) {
     bullet.splice(i, 1);
   }
 }
}

function keyDown(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 39) rightKey = true;
 else if (e.keyCode == 37) leftKey = true;
 if (e.keyCode == 38) upKey = true;
 else if (e.keyCode == 40) downKey = true;
 if (e.keyCode == 32 && bullet.length <= bulletTotal) bullet.push([player_x + 25, player_y - 20, 4, 20]);

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

[image]

full code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/06thgqns/2/

Edit by 2017/3/5
Thanks SpiderPig.I make the bullets objects 
Here is my new code
full code here:

```
bullet = [];
```

[image]

```
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="600"></canvas>
```

but It have a problem, when I double kick the shoot key space
the first bullets is disappeared,  it cant continuous fire.

what is the problem , thanks

full code on :http://jsfiddle.net/06thgqns/4/

Comment: You should make the bullets objects and not arrays. Then give each bullet a `speedX` and `speedY` property.

Comment: Thanks  SpiderPig , I update my new code http://jsfiddle.net/06thgqns/4/

Comment: but I find my problem ,when I double kick the shoot key(space)
the first bullets is disappeared, it cant continuous fire. thanks

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/boewvsu3/ - it shoots in the direction you are moving

Comment: Thank you  SpiderPig!!!!!!! prefect answer ,I love you so much, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Very easy, just modify

```
 bullet[i][1] -= 10;
```

to

```
 bullet[i][0] -= 10; //left , you can modify bullet[i][0] += 10; to change the direction to right
```